# Android Webview caching works in version 4.0.x but not in 2.3.3

Tags: java, android

I am facing a very strange issue. My jquery webview works offline in browsers and in `android version 4.0.x`. However, it does no work offline in lower versions.

Code for setting cache mode :

```
if(isConnected) {
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
} else {
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
}
```